# Redefine pi to uppi with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I'd like to use `unicode-math` to use ISO-style fonts for my formulae. However, I'd like to use `\pi` instead of `\uppi` to create an upright pi. Unfortunately, my redefinition with `\renewcommand` doesn't work.

How can I redefine the meaning of `\pi` to give an upright pi, while sticking with `math-style=ISO` and `bold-style=ISO` for the remaining letters?

At the moment I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\renewcommand{\pi}{\uppi} % doesn't work

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    \alpha \beta \Alpha \Beta\\
    \pi \uppi % these commands should show the same glyph
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until the range feature is fixed, you can use an indirect redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\umathpi\pi
  \renewcommand\pi{\symup\umathpi}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\alpha \beta \Alpha \Beta
\\
\pi \uppi \mitpi
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Notes

1. I don't recommend doing this; better define `\cpi` for “constant pi”, say `\newcommand{\cpi}{\symup{\pi}}`
2. Loading `amssymb` and `amsfonts` is useless, as all symbols and fonts are already provided by `unicode-math`
3. Don't load `fontenc` along with `fontspec`/`unicode-math` unless you have a very good reason to
4. Never use the `minimal` class (see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114))